# Ranking formula in excel based on two columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to rank the following items based on price using the following formula `=SUMPRODUCT(([Item]=[@Item])*([@Price]<[Price]))+1`, but it isn't returning any results:

[image]

When I use the same formula in the following test table it works, `=SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$7=A2)*(B2<$B$2:$B$7))+1`:

[image]

Can someone please let me know what I am doing wrong? Thanks

EDIT 2 : Evaluation https://i.stack.imgur.com/NzdZU.jpg

Comment: Can't repro. https://i.stack.imgur.com/OFXcu.png.

Comment: @BigBen the first four letter are text and the last five a dates. They were concatenated (item and date).

Comment: @JvdV I'm not sure thats the problem, tried it.

Comment: Can you evaluate the formula? That should give a clue to why it's returning 1.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that your calculations are set on manual. That would return `1` in all cases. Sidenote: You might want to do the same calculations, but instead with `COUNTIFS`

Comment: @BigBen this is the result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gyOYT.png

Comment: @JvdV calculations are set to manual. This is odd as it's working fine for the test table

Comment: Then change to automatic for starters.

Comment: @BigBen its on automatic. I've also tried to calculate sheet and calculate now without success

Comment: Ok ... step through when you're evaluating. That screenshot is just the end result.

Comment: @BigBen I've updated my post with the evaluation results

Comment: So your items are simply different (notice the `FALSE` values, especially the first `FALSE` in the first array which evaluates if the second item is equal to the first). You might want to show us how you concatenate your items.

Comment: Also, in your screenshots all items are actually completely different. What did you expect to get returned? This does not match your initial sample data at all. The outcome in your screenshots are completely valid and logical

Comment: @JvdV its the same table, I'm trying to see if I would get different results, this is how I'm concatenating the data https://imgur.com/a/HQNhgXB. The second value is date

Comment: As far as we can tell from your provided screenshots in evaluation, you have definately used a different table. All values under item are unique.

Comment: @JvdV Its data from the same table, I just changed the table style

Comment: It's different data. Look at your own screenshot, then compare it against the values you posten in your initial question

Comment: @JvdV yes the data is different (same format, from same table), I was trying different values to troubleshoot, but I'm still getting the same value (1). My bad, I should've posted the same table.

Comment: Yes please post the same set of screenshots but for the correct data.

Comment: @JvdV screenshot has been updated.

Comment: Not sure what you changed, but from what I see it's again different values across the board

Comment: what is the formula you used for `Item`? Try to add **TRIM(formula)** without changing your SUMPRODUCT formula, see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Your formula works fine for me.

Are you sure that A2 and A3 are the same value? There may be some hidden white space causing problems. Just try

```
=A2=A3
```

in another cell to make sure they are the same.

**USE `COUNTIFS` INSTEAD**

I don't know why your formula isn't working, however, I would suggest avoiding `SUMPRODUCT` where you can.

```
=COUNTIFS([Item],[@Item],[Price],">"&[@Price])+1
```

This will count the number of prices higher than the current one for each item (+1, if you want the rank to start at 1 instead of 0)

[image: =COUNTIFS([Item],[@Item],[Price],">"&[@Price])+1]

Comment: I would also suggest `COUNTIFS`, but as for leading/trailing spaces, OP could try: `=SUMPRODUCT((TRIM([Item])=TRIM([@Item]))*([@Price]<[Price]))+1`

Comment: I'm still getting the same results @JvdV

Comment: @aab Even using `COUNTIFS`?

Comment: @Gravitate yes, that as well

Comment: And have you done as I suggested with `=A2=A3`... I think your item values MUST be different in some way.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to get the ranking for each unique item, `=SUMPRODUCT(([Item]=[@Item])*([Price]>[@Price]))+1` should do the trick. If the goal is to get the ranking based only on price, don't have it figured out yet.

Comment: I'm trying to rank based on price